# how can i verify if the username and password is validate with the database using mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql

I try to verify the user input with the database. Everything goes good but it looks like the query don't run. i am using maria Db as my database there is a table name user_gegevens.

case 2:

```
//
//myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);


try {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
    String username1 = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
    String password1 = sc.nextLine();

    Connection Conn;
    Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/memorygame","root","");
    Statement st;

    st = Conn.createStatement();



    String sqlverf = "Select * from user_gegevens where Username ='"+username1+"' and Password ='"+password1+"'";

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlverf);

    if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("sdada");
    }


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: "Looks like" is not a good description. Add print statements to the else part as well and describe what happens. What kind of error do you get? Apart from that having an empty root password is a really bad idea and may not work and you should check PreparedStatement for passing parameters and not store passwords in clear text...

Comment: i dont get a error when i choose for the case two i use a switch. I have a case one to register user en case 2 for the login register worked there is a insert query for that. but when i use the case 2 evrything is working fine i can put the username en password but after that nothing is happening